# Substitute NA values in place without modification in R

Tags: r, na

I have a matrix with a few `NA` values in it, and I would like them to be substituted with empty strings.

```
m <- matrix(letters, ncol=8, nrow=3)
m[c(3, 8, 14, 17, 22)] <- NA
```

Is there a way to substitute `NA` values with `""` without modifying the variable `m`? For example, I'd like to do the following without changing `m`.

```
m[is.na(m)] <- ""
some_function(m)
```

So something that would effectively do this, but in base `R`:

```
na_to_empty_string(m)  # returns new matrix without changing m
```

Note, I am trying to create a temporary matrix with empty strings instead of `NA`s, not print it (where we could use `print(m, na.string="")`. Functions like `na.omit()` appear to omit entire rows, not just cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `replace` to not change the original object 'm'.

```
replace(m, is.na(m), '')
```